# verification mail sent in gmail spam when link included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am sending verification email with activation link.

My activation link in email is :

```
http://abc.com/activate?activation_code=1234&email=abc@abc.com
```

But when I change acivation link like

```
http://abc.com?activation_code=1234&email=abc@abc.com
```

It goes into gmail inbox. 
what is the reason and what should I do to send first link in email and avoid spaming in gmail..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to remove the &email=, and just activate him through the code and see if its also landing in the spam.. (`http://abc.com?activation_code=1234`)

Comment: It did works 'http://abc.com/?activation_code=1234&email=abc@gmail.com' and goes into inbox but when I send link  '(http://abc.com/activate?activation_code=1234)'. It goes into spam.

Comment: The behavior will be different for different recipients. If it landed in your inbox, does not mean all your recipients will also get it in their inbox. Google spam filters rate an email based on a users history. Hence, what is a spam for me may not be for someone else. [Read this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any suggestion on how to avoid a spam filter are just guess work. If it was that obvious, wouldn't spammers use the same tricks?

What I can tell you is that you need to build a reputation of **not** sending spam emails from your servers. And that takes a while to happen. Then you should guard that reputation by not letting spammers relay from your servers.

There are hundreds of settings you need to do on your MTA. Listing here a few

1. Stick to one IP address to relay your emails
2. Get a reverse DNS mapped to that IP address
3. Set SPF record
4. Sign your emails with DKIM
5. Setup DMARC
6. Signup for FBL, so that you get a feedback whenever your email is marked as a SPAM by your recipient.
7. Setup correct headers. There are a bunch of those. You can test your outgoing email headers using [this free tool from Postmark](http://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/)
8. ...

All these measures will help an Email service provider (or ESP) (such as Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo etc.) to validate that the email actually originated from where it claims it did.

Beyond this, there is little you can do. Despite of doing all these, your email can continue to land in spam folder if your recipients keep marking it as spam. So make your users happy. Don't send them emails if they don't want to receive.

In the meanwhile, you could use some professional help by using an ESP such as [Send Grid](http://www.sendgrid.com) for your outgoing emails. They would have already built a good reputation of sending high quality emails. They will take all the pains to ensure their IP addresses maintain high reputation.

[Read about some advice from Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126)

Comment: @EternalLearner  your 7 points are cool. but need to figure it out why this link (http://abc.com?activation_code=1234) goes into INBOX and this (http://abc.com/activate?activation_code=1234) goes into SPAM.

Comment: No one other than Google can answer that authentically. For all you know, this may not be the behavior on another gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are including the email in the link there is a high probability that this can be marked as spam.

Generate a unique key and then in your application you can correlate it with the user. Also include in the mail body as much information about the user as you can, this will help to reduce the probability of being marked as spam.

Also take a look at this [article](http://www.fulcrumtech.net/resources/avoiding-gmail-spam-filter/), where it provides some ways to avoid the spam filter.